Is Ceftazidime effective for treating mycoplasma
My pet was very sick so we took it to the vet
The vet said it was likely mycoplasma infection and gave an injection of Ceftazidime
However, when I researched online it appears that beta lactam antibiotics are ineffective agains mycoplasma, so who is right, me or the veterinarian

If in doubt, ask another vet for a second opinion. If you don't trust the first on medication advice, why do you trust their diagnosis?

@keshlam
It isn’t that I don’t trust the vet, just that I don’t see how the medication given would help!

The veterinarian said he wasn’t sure it was mycoplasma without further testing but that it was the most likely culprit

Have you asked the vet how it will help? It may be an off-label use, but could be entirely legitimate..

@keshlam
But cephalosporin antibiotics like ceftazidime work by disrupting the bacterial cell wall and mycoplasma doesn’t have a cell wall

See my answer for my best semi-informed guess. Real answer is to always ask your doctor how a treatment will help before accepting it, if you insist on second guessing them. Sometimes the right answer is to refuse treatment if the treatment won't help significantly ... but you have to talk to the doctor. True for human medicine too.

Mycoplasma pneumonias, at least in humans, often recover well in their own. I suspect the broad-spectrum antibiotic is to guard against secondary infections.
But I'm not a vet, or a doctor. I would strongly suggest you ask your own vet why this was prescribed in this specific case. Especially since, having already been administered, it's pretty much a moot question.

That makes sense thanks
